# How do you avoid name mangling of C++ procedures?

Tags: visual-c++, definition, dllexport

```
__declspec(dllexport) public void CallMe(wchar_t *p);
```

The compiled dll renames the "CallMe" procedure to "?CallMe@@ZAPPA_G@Z". How do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extern "C" { } block around your definitions to avoid the C++ name mangling.